# A single word for "take tender loving care"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that can be used instead of the phrase "give tender loving care"? As in

> "Tom gives tender loving care to his plants."

I am looking for a word to be used in relation to taking care of plants, as in the above example.

Comment: [Cherish](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cherish) is the word I use to describe...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tom [NURTURES](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/nurture) his plants.

Merriam-Webster has the following example sentence, which is close to what you want to say:

You have to carefully nurture the vines if you want them to produce good grapes.

Comment: Exactly, somehow nurtures slipped my mind.